# Basic Algebra + basic calculus/ find the equation of a line

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Find the equation of the line tangent to the graph of $f$ at $(1, -3)$, where $f$ is given by $f(x) = 6x^3 − 13x^2 + 4$. Use $y$ as the dependent variable when you write your equation.

My answer which was false:

The $f'(x)= 18x^2-26x$
$f'(1) = 18-26 = -8$

the equation $(y+3)=-8(x-1)$
$y= -8x+5 $

but it was false, so could any one help please :)

Comment: Small note: If you don't feel up to speed with TeX, you can always do ² and ³ by holding down left alt and typing 252 and 253 respectively on the numkeypad, and then releasing (assuming you have Windows, at least).

Comment: Then again LaTeX is not so hard for what you're doing, basically put \$ around your equations, and do ^ for exponentiation

Answer (score 1):

The answer and solution you posted is correct, here's a plot
[image: plot]

Comment: But it is derivative, and your graph is for the f(x)

Comment: @john12 The question says "Find the equation of the line tangent to the graph of $f$", this is what you did, and that is what this is a plot of.

Answer (score 0):

Just a point on form.

Some students tend to memorize things such as point-slope form of an equation. When I was is school, I only memorized one form of such equations, namely

$$m = \Delta y /\Delta x$$

or in your case
$$-8 = \Delta y / \Delta x$$
$$-8 = (y - (-3)) / (x-1)$$
$$-8 = (y + 3) / (x-1)$$
$$(y + 3) = -8(x-1)$$
Which is what you started with.

Try showing more work. It just makes everything easier to understand.